# cache using cacheable="false" in catalog_product_view.xml not working?

Tags: magento2, cache

I need your help. I tried so many times to disable product view...

I modified the `addtocart.phtml` and need to uncached to work, (when cache is enabled is not working ok) now i have to left the web page cache disable and obviously is too slowly

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" 
       name="product.info.addtocart.additional"
       as="product.info.addtocart"
       template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"
       cacheable="false" />
```

I read a lot in forums but i can't find the real problem, i know with this `cacheable="false"` its not the best way because all the page was uncached, but at least all the rest of the web will ride fast.

Can you help me please?

Comment: try to disable the full page cache

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html more than likely you'll need to do more than just modify the phtml and create your own block and dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

If using `cacheable="false"`, the whole page will be uncached. The performance will be impacted significantly. Try to use another way(should use Ajax to load dynamic data).